# How to create multiple sheets in csv using python

Tags: python

I created a csv file with single sheet. I want to know how to create csv file with multiple sheets using python language.

Comment: csv does not support multiple sheet. Use xlwt ro create and xls file and create multiple sheets within a workbook

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Start with [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 4):

A csv file is a simple file type with flat data, separated by commas. Unlike an excel file, for example, it cannot contain multiple sheets.
If you need multiple sheets, you will have to make multiple csv files.